# c# how to refer to current button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a minesweeper game using Windows Application. I would like to use a switch inside a method.

The problem:

```
public void switcher()
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("empty.jpg"); // look at A1
            break;
        case 1:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("1.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("2.jpg");
            break;
        case 3:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("3.jpg");
            break;
        case 4:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("4.jpg");
            break;
        case 5:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("5.jpg");
            break;
        case 6:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("6.jpg");
            break;
        case 7:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("7.jpg");
            break;
        case 8:
            A1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("8.jpg");
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, each of them says "A1. ....." A1 is my first button's name, but there are many other buttons as well. Is there a way I can refer to the button's properties, such as background image, without having to use its name? It would make programming so much easier.

Here's a simplified part of the button, if it helps:

```
private void A1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // < - I want to refer to this without using A1 name.
{
    x = bombcount[0, 0];
    switcher();      
}
```

**edit: One of the answers worked. I don't know much about these things, but I'll try to learn more about them! Thank you!**

Comment: `switcher()` should have an argument of type Button.  That way you can use the logic on any button you want.  Simply pass in A1, B1, C1, etc as needed. `switcher(A1)`

Comment: It's right there in the arguments - `sender` is the actual control causing the event handler to be invoked. Just cast it to `Button`, pass it to `switcher` and you're done (you don't really need the switch either, by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference in switcher to the button being clicked like this:

```
     private void A1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
             Button myB = (Button) sender; 
             x = bombcount[0,0];
             switcher(myB);
     }

     private void switcher(Button button)
     {
          switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("empty.jpg"); // look at A1
            break;
        case 1:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("1.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("2.jpg");
            break;
        case 3:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("3.jpg");
            break;
        case 4:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("4.jpg");
            break;
        case 5:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("5.jpg");
            break;
        case 6:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("6.jpg");
            break;
        case 7:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("7.jpg");
            break;
        case 8:
            button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("8.jpg");
            break;
    }
     }
```

Comment: "try" is not an answer. Explain what you changed.

Comment: Sorry for leaving out the explanation: Introduced a reference to the button being clicked in the switcher method.

Comment: You have a lot of time on your hands, don't you?

Comment: Oh, my bad for trying to explain how you can write better answers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to refactor this code altogether. Don't rely on private members such as `x` like that, use method parameters:

```
private void SetButtonImage(Button button, int number)
{
    string imagePath;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        imagePath = "empty.jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        imagePath = number + ".jpg";
    }

    button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    int number = bombcount[0, 0];

    SetButtonImage(button, number);
}
```

Now you can hook up all button click events to that single event handler, and you can remove the `x` member, and you can remove the switch altogether.